# Google My Business API Access - Admin or owner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

following [this example](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup?hl=de#make-simple-http-request), I wanted to make a request to the API.
I get this result:

```js
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "vettedState": "NOT_VETTED", 
      "type": "PERSONAL", 
      "name": "accounts/xxxxx", 
      "verificationState": "UNVERIFIED", 
      "accountName": "xxxx."
    }
  ]
}
```

Do I need to be the owner of the account, to get access?
Currently, I am an admin.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a manager or owner of an account, you currently only seem the have access to your personal default account, which might be empty.